# how to safely restart postgresql container in kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, k3s

I have a small hobby website I want to release on my server. I chose to use kubernetes for that, as I partly use it at work as well, so I'd like to get familiar. I bought hetzner debian server and installed k3s. Now are deploying PostgreSQL container (version 15.2, not cluster) as per this [tutorial](https://www.containiq.com/post/deploy-postgres-on-kubernetes). (I did a minor changes I saw from other tutorials, should not be relevant).

It runs fine, I was happy with it. But I tried to restart deployment to make sure data are not lost if server goes down for some reason. After a few restarts, database is corrupted.

Once I saw:

```
PANIC:  invalid magic number 0000 in log segment 000000010000000000000000, offset 0
```

another time:

```
invalid contrecord length 1174 (expected 48430224) at 0/195BC90
```

another time:

```
PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
```

When I tried to google how to recover from this, I did not find any safe options and mostly the suggestions were to restore backup.

So my question is, how do I safely restart/shutdown PostgreSQL container? Am I missing some shutdown config for PostgreSQL pod in k8s?

Update 1:

I was restarting deployment from k9s with `r` command. I think UI made it look like it was rotated right away, but it probably takes some time. So I think I triggered multiple restarts every 10 seconds and that might have corrupted the DB. Anyway I added `terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60` and used `preStop` hook from answer. Thanks

Update 2:
I imported DB, did a restart and again same issue:

> could not locate a valid checkpoint record

Update 3:
**I replaced `Deployment` with `StatefulSet` and it seems to be handling restarts better. Tried over 10 restarts and no issues. Whereas before it crashed around 4th restart.**

Comment: How did you restart the pod? Did you force him somehow or did you wait for him to be gracefully killed?
Tendentially, in non-K8s environments just restarting the linux service will achieve your goal, for this I think it was simply forcibly killed…

Comment: Anyway, I recommend using the new Operator postgresql K8s --> https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/cloud-native-postgresql-helm
Your operation will improve a lot.

Comment: I restarted deployment in k9s, there is a command `r` with confirmation. I'll read about operator, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the best practice is using an operator like [cloudnative-pg](https://cloudnative-pg.io/) or [postgres-operator](https://postgres-operator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but they are pretty big and probably have way more feature for a simple workload. Here is a simple solution for your problem.

### Solution

Add below to your pod spec

```yaml
preStop:
  exec:
    command: ["/usr/local/bin/pg_ctl stop -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -w -t 60 -m fast"]
```

### Explanation

Basically when you kill a pod, Kubernetes signals `SIGTERM` and gives 30 seconds for your pod, after that time it sends `SIGKILL`. When postgres receive `SIGTERM` it won't accept net connections but it won't terminate existing terminations, so any client will block db's termination, and after 30 seconds pod will receive `SIGKILL` which is very bad for postgres [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-shutdown.html). So you need to safely shutdown postgres somehow, with `preStop` hook you can.

#### Kubernetes

This is the exact chronological order of your pod:

1. Set `state=Terminating` from Pod controller
2. `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` timer starts (default is 30 seconds)
3. `preStop` hook: `pg_cli ...`
4. `SIGTERM` is sent: Postgres won't accept new connections
5. k8s waits until `terminationGracePeriods` (configurable from yaml)
6. If app is still alive `SIGKILL` is sent

Also you need to set `.spec.strategy.type==Recreate` in Deployment.

### Postgres

For the `pg_cli` commands you can refer this summary, most useful one for you looks like `-m fast`.

`SIGTERM`:

- "Smart Shutdown Mode"
- Disallows new connections
- Let's existing connections continue

`SIGINT`:

- "Fast Shutdown Mode"
- Disallow new connections
- Send `SIGTERM` to existing servers processes (?) they'll exit promptly

`SIGQUIT`:

- "Immediate Shutdown Mode"
- Send `SIGQUIT` to all child processes, if they don't terminate in 5 secs sends `SIGKILL`

EDIT:

Apparently `Recreate` only guarantees *recreation* for update (old rs to new rs), but it **does not guarantee 1 pod at a time** if pod randomly dies. While new pod is creating old one may be in terminating phase, and because of race condition data may be corrupt. [Relevant Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#recreate-deployment)

> This will only guarantee Pod termination previous to creation for upgrades. If you upgrade a Deployment, all Pods of the old revision will be terminated immediately. Successful removal is awaited before any Pod of the new revision is created. If you manually delete a Pod, the lifecycle is controlled by the ReplicaSet and the replacement will be created immediately (even if the old Pod is still in a Terminating state). **If you need an "at most" guarantee for your Pods, you should consider using a StatefulSet.**

Comment: nice, seems to be working. But mostly I think I was restarting deployment in the middle of other restart. I think k9s showed it in a way I thought it was done, so I triggered another restart in the middle of previous restart. I added preStop hook, increased terminationGracePeriodSeconds and if I restart slowly, I can't reproduce corrupted DB. Thank you for comprehensive answer!

Comment: hmm, I did import the DB, ran Restart command again and DB is corrupted again:
"could not locate a valid checkpoint record"

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment, can you try again I added a new `Deployment` parameter .spec.strategy.type==Recreate

Comment: with statefulset it works fine :)

Comment: Switching to a K8s Operator for PostgreSQL can create new problems. You effectively add another layer of abstraction over your PostgreSQL database and if that layer breaks (as it has done repeatedly for me) you can lose your entire data, even though the actual database may still exist.